# What does udevd process do during the boot time?

Tags: boot, udev

Ubuntu 11.04 boot time is 80 seconds 67 of which belong to the udevd process. Here's what dmesg shows:

```
[    6.534288] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   73.216006] udevd[399]: starting version 175
```

What udevd does and is it possible to reduce the time of its work?

Answer (score 7):

The required device information is exported by the sysfs file system. For every device the kernel has detected and initialized, a directory with the device name is created. It contains attribute files with device-specific properties.

Every time a device is added or removed, the kernel sends a uevent to notify udev of the change. The udev daemon reads and parses all provided rules from the /etc/udev/rules.d/*.rules files once at start-up and keeps them in memory. If rules files are changed, added or removed, the daemon can reload the in-memory representation of all rules with the command udevadm control reload_rules. This is also done when running /etc/init.d/boot.udev reload.

[source](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.udev.html#sec.udev.rules)

To know how to optimize a boot time please see [this](http://www.embedded-linux.co.uk/downloads/WE-2.2Paper_Simmonds.pdf) pdf file

[This](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/06/some-nifty-udev-rules-and-examples/) also would help you

If you want to check if there is a device stoping udev use this command

`udevadm trigger -v`

Comment: Unfortuantely, this user did not stock around, as this is a very good answer deserving of recognition.

Comment: both "this" links are dead